# Failed to get tenure then hired by another institute, is the new position tenure or not?

Tags: tenure-track

Due to bad personality a person was not granted tenure after working for six years in a university. Eventually, the person left and got hired as an associate professor in another university. Would this be a tenure position or tenure track position?

Comment: Is this a riddle or something?  In real life: ask someone at the institution in question for the answer.  The department chair would certainly know.

Answer (score 8):

It's not really possible to know, just from this person's job title, whether they have tenure or not.

At some universities, the title "associate professor" automatically implies "tenured". But at others, it is possible to have the title of associate professor but not have tenure - unusual, but possible. Since this person has had a relatively unusual career path, this is a little more likely. Still, you can't be sure unless you ask them, or unless the university makes their tenure status public in some other way.

Comment: It's quite common in my experience for someone with several years of experience as an assistant professor to be hired as a tenure track associate professor at another university, typically with a shortened tenure process.  It's also possible that this person was hired with tenure as an associate professor, but that's less common in my experience.

Comment: Another example I'm familiar with is a tenured associate professor at a "lesser" school getting an offer with the same rank of associate at a "better" school, but on a shortened (relative to an assistant professor on the tenure track) tenure process.

Answer (score 6):

A few universities routinely use the title "associate professor without tenure." Even at universities like mine, where associate professors almost always have tenure, there are (at least) two situations where an associate professor might not have tenure. (1) The person has done research commensurate with the title of associate professor but has no teaching experience. (2) We are trying to offer a position (to someone at another university) quickly because of competition with other schools.  Getting approval from the college administration and the provost for a tenured offer takes more time than getting approval for a non-tenured offer. So we might offer a non-tenured position quickly with the understanding that it will be upgraded to tenure when we get the necessary administrative approval (and, if we don't get approval for a tenured offer, then we'll recommend promotion to tenure next year).